# How to load custom dataset for feeding to CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, mnist

MNIST use the below code to load data:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I have prepared custom dataset and want to load the same. So, tried the below code:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = (('C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte'),('C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte')), (('C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\test-images-idx3-ubyte'),('C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\test-labels-idx1-ubyte'))
```

where t10k-images-idx3-ubyte is custom image training data
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte is custom label training data
test-images-idx3-ubyte is custom image test data
test-labels-idx1-ubyte is custom label test data

But it is saving it as a string in `(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)`.
Could you please help me with the correct way to load this data to
 `(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you just assign tuple of strings to the variables:

```
train_images = 'C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte'
train_labels = 'C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte'
test_images = 'C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\test-images-idx3-ubyte'
test_labels = 'C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\test-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

To load your own dataset you should create custom loader to read the images and feed them to your network. You could examine the example of such a loader, for example, here: https://medium.com/@waleedka/traffic-sign-recognition-with-tensorflow-629dffc391a6 (function *load_data*).

Comment: Hi , thanks @cyberspace   Although, I use your load_data function but it shows the below error when I just change the path and f.endswith("ubyte")       OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Users\\sm50014\\Desktop\\new\\train\\image\\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte'>